# CSS margin shorthand

Tags: css

I like to use some *helper* CSS class, like `.mv10` (which stands for *margin vertical 10*), see:

```
.mv10 {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

Is there a way to write these CSS rules in **shorthand** mode without mess up the `margin-left` and `margin-right` values?

Something like

```
.mv10 {
    margin: 10px <keep> 10px <keep> !important;
}
```

Comment: No should you really create 'helper classes' *that* specific...you'll just bloat your CSS.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to write these CSS rules in shorthand mode without mess[ing] up the `margin-left` and `margin-right` values?

Yes.

There is one way and one way only.

You write the more general rules higher up the cascade than the more specific rules.

That's *exactly* how the cascade is supposed to work.

ie.

**CSS:**

```
.mv10 {
margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.myclass {
margin-right: 6px;
margin-left: 6px;
}

.myotherclass {
margin-right: 9px;
}

.mythirdclass {
padding-top: 12px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mv10 myclass"></div>
<div class="mv10 myotherclass"></div>
<div class="mv10 mythirdclass"></div>
```